# convert date yyyy-mm-dd to mmm-yy SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert date yyyy-mm-dd (stored as a date format) to mmm-yy format.

There are no exact matches in the prior questions on the site.

I have tried substrings and convert function, was considering creating a scalar function but its taking me a while and hoping someone has an easy solution.

Comment: Dates don't have formats in RDBMS. Worry about the formats in your presentation layer. Storing values like `'Apr-19'` means that (according to your data) December 2010 is **after** April 2020.

Comment: There might be no exact matches but that's a basic skill in IT - working out what to do without having exact info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct the format using string operations:

```
select left(datename(month, datecol), 3) + '-' + right(datename(year, datecol), 2)
```

Or using `format()`:

```
select format(datecol, 'MMM-yy')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select replace(right(convert(varchar(9), getdate(), 6), 6), ' ', '') asDate
```